# How to configure test_settings with Nightwatch.js

Tags: nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I would like to use Nightwatch.js to test my app in multiple deployment environments and multiple browsers. How can I do this efficiently when launch_url, selenium_host, and desiredCapabilities are specified together in test_settings. Can I do this without creating a bunch of environments like local-firebox, local-chrome, local-safari, ci-firefox, ci-safari, local-unit-tests, ci-unit-tests, etc.